# How do I get list of sheets in a spreadsheet dynamically with google sheets api in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-sheets-api

Is there a way to get a list of all sheets in the below google sheet? See `ranges=${sheet}`. The code below gets data from one sheet but I'd like to get a list of sheets so I can call them dynamically.

```
const API = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sheetID}/values:batchGet?ranges=${sheet}&majorDimension=ROWS&key=${key}`;

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch(API).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
            console.log(data)

            let rows = data.valueRanges[0].values;

          });
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the sheet names in the Spreadsheet using the API key.

  - You have already known the Spreadsheet ID.
- The Spreadsheet is publicly shared.
- You want to achieve this using `fetch` of Javascript.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Modification point:

- In order to retrieve the sheet names in the Spreadsheet, the method of spreadsheets.get in Sheets API is used.

#### Script 1:

The sample script for retrieving the sheet names in the Spreadsheet is as follows.

```
const endpoint = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sheetID}?key=${key}`;
fetch(endpoint).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
  const sheetNames = data.sheets.map(sheet => sheet.properties.title);
  console.log(sheetNames)
});
```

#### Script 2:

When your script is modified, how about the following modification? In this modified script, the values are retrieved from all sheets in the Spreadsheet.

```
const endpoint = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sheetID}?key=${key}`;
fetch(endpoint).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
  data.sheets.forEach(s => {
    const sheetName = s.properties.title;
    const API = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sheetID}/values:batchGet?ranges=${sheetName}&majorDimension=ROWS&key=${key}`;
    fetch(API).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
      console.log(data)

      let rows = data.valueRanges[0].values;
    });
  });
});
```

#### Script 3:

In this script, the values are retrieved from only the 1st sheet in the Spreadsheet.

```
fetch(endpoint).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
  const sheetName = data.sheets[0].properties.title;
  const API = `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/${sheetID}/values:batchGet?ranges=${sheetName}&majorDimension=ROWS&key=${key}`;
  fetch(API).then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
    console.log(data)

    let rows = data.valueRanges[0].values;
  });
});
```

#### Note:

- If you want to retrieve the values from the specific sheet in the Spreadsheet, please modify the above script.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @sbaden Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: If I were to convert the above to include authorization where would you suggest I find a simple example? I don't find the API docs very user friendly. They are very confusing.

Comment: @sbaden I have to apologize. Because unfortunately, I cannot understand about your new question. So how about posting it as new question? By this, it will help users think of the solution. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.